# Does diffusion of matter (Fick s law) happens at null temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

If yes : is diffusion of matter due due temperature ? Why the formula does not include temperature ? Thank you

Comment: The diffusion coefficient is often a strong function of temperature.

Comment: All right. Thank you for that hint. But so, is there diffusion at null temperature, is diffusion exactly null in this case ?

Comment: At zero Kelvin, which you can't reach, there is no energy in the system and diffusion does not occur.

Comment: All right. Thank you Jon for your useful help.